# How to generate a List<String> with zeep?

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I'm using the Python library [zeep](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to talk to a SOAP service. One of the required arguments in the documentation is of type `List<String>` and in the WSDL I found this:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IncludedLenders" type="tns:ArrayOfString"/>
```

And I believe `AraryOfString` is defined as:

```
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

How do I make zeep generate the values for that? I tried with:

```
"IncludedLenders": [
  "BMS",
  "BME"
]
```

but that generates:

```
                <ns0:IncludedLenders>
                    <ns0:string>BMS</ns0:string>
                </ns0:IncludedLenders>
```

instead of:

```
                <ns0:IncludedLenders>
                    <ns0:string>BMS</ns0:string>
                    <ns0:string>BME</ns0:string>
                </ns0:IncludedLenders>
```

Any ideas how to generate the later?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out. First I needed to extract the `ArrayOfString` type:

```
array_of_string_type = client.get_type("ns1:ArrayOfString")
```

and then create it this way:

```
"IncludedLenders": array_of_string_type(["BMS","BME"])
```

Comment: Worth noting, this also works with any ArrayOfXXX like objects, including custom ones (ex "ns0:ArrayOfGarantie"); In any case the intermediate objects (string, Garantie, ...) are "magically" created, so you don't need to create them ! (I ended with Array of Object of Object at my first attempt)